# How to secure old routers with WPA2 and with old firmware?

Tags: network, wifi, wpa2

There are many old routers that support WPA2 that hadn't had a firmware update released since around 2010. Is it possible to secure their WPA2 implementation considering the more recent vulnerabilities discovered in WPA/WPA2? Configuration, process, turning on/off features?

Comment: I edited the question to focus on the response to the weaknesses.

Comment: Not sure what routers you are talking about, but common consumer Wifi routers I know just allow you to configure the WPA mode, the encryption algorithm and the passphrase. Also most vulnerabilities discovered in Wifi chipsets require a new Wifi firmware blog. As long as there is not an updates OS available for your routers like OpenWRT you should consider the routers as EOL = electronic junk.